# How to use git client with github on RedHat 6.4

Tags: git, github, redhat, openssh, libcrypto

Does anyone know the way to run git client with github on RedHat 6.4?

It stopped working latelty with github see: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

> RedHat < 6.8 is not compatible with the recent changes because it does
>   not support TLSv1.2.

`Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx.git/': SSL connect error`

We need to test software on 6.4, as this is what is on production, but right now due to above issue cannot clone git repo directly on 6.4, and cannot update RedHat.
Maybe we can update just some crypto libs to the newer versions and/or compile newer git client from sources?

Anyone had similar issue and can advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found much easier fix (so adding here for others):

```
yum update -y nss curl libcurl
```

above fixed the issue for me (without the need for recompiling anything)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile OpenSSL, OpenSSH and git.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i found a better solution (will answer my own question just if someone needs it :))